# comparing between two banks , how do i compare between these two bank and display which bank is better

Tags: java

if (jumlahKeseluruhan > jumlahKeseluruhan1){

```
System.out.println ("Cadangan ialah bank A");
}
else if (jumlahKeseluruhan < jumlahKeseluruhan1){
    System.out.println ("Cadangan ialah bank B")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is jumlahKeseluruhan defined. Where is the class declaration.
For comparing the objects, you need to make a method inside the class for comparison.

There must be a parameter for comparison. See below example

```
class Bank {
    private int share;  // Let it be a parameter for comparison

    public Bank(int s) {
        share = s;
    }

    public int getShare() {
        return share;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then compare them like this

```
Bank bank1 = new Bank(100);
Bank bank2 = new Bank(200);

if( bank1.getShare() < bank2.getShare() ) {
    // Do stuff
} else {
    // Do other stuff
}
```